# Update query by combining three tables with Temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make a temp table by combining three tables using an update query. These are the steps I followed but there may be a way to improve the queries to have better performance. Please help me

**Step1**: Created #TempTable1 temp table by joining Table1 and table2 on `structureNodeid` with where condition is `PeriodId` = 728.

```
 SELECT
  t1.TRUOB,
  t1.TRUGM,
  t1.NGLBBLR,
  t1.structureNodeid,
  sn.Dellid,
  t1.Periodid INTO #TempTable1
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.structureNodeId = t2.id
WHERE t1.PeriodId = 728;
```

**STEP2**: Created #TempTable2 temp table by joining Table1 and table2 on `structureNodeid` with where condition is `PeriodId` = 737.

```
SELECT
  t1.PYTRUOGB2,
  t1.PYTRUOGM2,
  t1.TRUOB,
  t1.TRUGM,
  t1.NGLBBLR,
  t1.structureNodeid,
  t2.Dellid,
  t1.Periodid INTO #TempTable2
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.structureNodeId = t2.id
WHERE t1.PeriodId = 737
```

**STEP3**: updating temp table (#TempTable2)

```
    UPDATE #TempTable2
SET #TempTable2.PYTRUOGB2 = ISNULL(T1.TRUOB, 0) + (ISNULL(T1.TRUGM, 0) / 6) + ISNULL(T1.NGLBBLR, 0),
    #tempTable2.PYTRUOGM2 = (ISNULL(T1.TRUOB, 0) * 6) + ISNULL(T1.TRUGM, 0) + (ISNULL(T1.NGLBBLR, 0) * 6)
FROM #TempTable2 T2
JOIN #TempTable1 T1
  ON T2.Dellid = T1.Dellid
```

**Step4**: Update the main table (Table1) with the original details

```
    UPDATE Table1
SET PYTRUOGB2 = T2.PYTRUOGB2,
    PYTRUOGM2 = T2.PYTRUOGM2
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN #TempTable2 T2
  ON T1.StructureNodeID = T2.StructureNodeID
```

the above implementation queries may not be the best in performance can you please help me to improve the performance by implementing better queries.

Comment: what is the version of your sqlserver

Comment: sql-server 2014 @Ajay2707

Comment: can you give the actual table data and required output in excel and paste here

Comment: okay @Ajay2707, let me do that

Comment: I don't know how many rows you are inserting to the temp tables, but you can create index separately for Dellid and StructureNodeID on them before update.

Comment: I am trying to insert data with 50 records @Serkan Arslan. Let me add the table data here.

Comment: @SivamohanReddy Can you also elaborate on which steps you are facing with performance issues?

Comment: "looks like a performance issue" - is it a performance issue or not?

Comment: @MitchWheat, yaa it is a performance issue, as it is taking 4 steps to update the data into the table. is there any way to execute in 2 steps

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why `Table2` is involved here, but this could be a simple self-joined update:

```sql
UPDATE t1_737
SET PYTRUOGB2 = ISNULL(t1_728.TRUOB, 0) + (ISNULL(t1_728.TRUGM, 0) / 6) + ISNULL(t1_728.NGLBBLR, 0),
    PYTRUOGM2 = (ISNULL(t1_728.TRUOB, 0) * 6) + ISNULL(t1_728.TRUGM, 0) + (ISNULL(t1_728.NGLBBLR, 0) * 6)
FROM Table1 t1_737
JOIN Table1 t1_728
  ON t1_737.StructureNodeID = t1_728.StructureNodeID
WHERE t1_737.PeriodId = 737
 AND t1_728.PeriodId = 728
```

If you do need `Table2` for filtering purposes, you can do this:

```sql
UPDATE t1_737
SET PYTRUOGB2 = ISNULL(t1_728.TRUOB, 0) + (ISNULL(t1_728.TRUGM, 0) / 6) + ISNULL(t1_728.NGLBBLR, 0),
    PYTRUOGM2 = (ISNULL(t1_728.TRUOB, 0) * 6) + ISNULL(t1_728.TRUGM, 0) + (ISNULL(t1_728.NGLBBLR, 0) * 6)
FROM Table1 t1_737
JOIN Table1 t1_728
  ON t1_737.StructureNodeID = t1_728.StructureNodeID
WHERE t1_737.PeriodId = 737
 AND t1_728.PeriodId = 728
 AND t1_737.structureNodeId IN (
   SELECT t2.id FROM Table2 t2
)
AND t1_728.structureNodeId IN (
   SELECT t2.id FROM Table2 t2
)
```